# Is there any option to change route and pass props to another component in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am at this path: `http://localhost:3034/dashboard/one`.

Now I want to pass a large object in another component `<Edit/>` that has an object and also change on the path to `http://localhost:3034/dashboard/edit`.

I don't want to use the next router to pass all objects with queries in URL. That one way, I know.

Example: `router.push("/dashboard/edit/" + object)`

I have data that pass from this slug: `http://localhost:3034/dashboard/one` to `http://localhost:3034/dashboard/edit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the router to pass your data, a few options are left.

- using a [Reducer](https://react-redux.js.org/): handy and powerful, but lots of boilerplate to get it working
- using a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html): powerful as well, a little tricky to master at first, and can trigger lots of redraws if not used properly
- using the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage): very easy to setup, but requires your data to be serializable, You can use libraries such as [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLocalStorage.md) to make your life easier
- refetch your item in your edit page using an `id`: you could have your url like `/dashboard/one/edit/` and fetch the data directly from that page instead of carrying the object around